# Project is empty at sonarqube

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Why after successful analysis at jenkin, my project is empty at `sonarqube`.

Console output at jenkin:-

[image]

Sonarqube scanner details:-

[image]

Sonarqube/localhost details:-

[image]

Comment: There is java code in jenkinsadhov folder?

Comment: No. There is no Java code in folder

Comment: I will remake my question. There is any code in any language in jenkinsadhoc folder?

Comment: Yes, the folder contains ios project written in swift language.

Answer (score 1):

Install [Swift](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SonarSwift) plugin in sonar. By default sonar check only java code. Then run jenkins job again.